# Granted privilege for USB mass storage

Tags: android

When I used different file explorer manager apps  (in android), they ask privileges for using (writing) mass storage, they show an activity to select the path 'for grant priviliges' (ex: esexplorer, asus file explorer) (see below)

[image: Activity launch by file explorer]

I see the directory : /storage/0000-0000 corresponding to my USB mass storage. But it is only in read mode, not allowing for writing.

How can I ask the permission to write on external usb mass storage by asking path similarly to the picture by launching this activity without rooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Storage Access Framework to write on removable devices.

Let the user pick a directory with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` or a file with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

You will then get the needed permissions too.